# Order Object by Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object in the qualification and I am not getting any indication of the key. I need to sort by value.

[image]

I did so:

let keysSorted = Object.values (arrCambo) .sort (function (a, b) {return arrCambo [a] -arrCambo [b]});
let sorted = keysSorted.sort ();

Generally, return is an array in which I lose the original values of the object I need!

Comment: I think we need a little more context do your question.  What are you trying to accomplish and where are you hung up?

Comment: May be this can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: You cannot order the properties of an Object. If you need this, convert the data structure to an array of objects instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Comment: @EMcG What you are trying to do is pick up objects and have them read alphabetically according to their value.

I see things on the internet, are done with sorting (), always looking at the key.

Comment: You should post the expected array to sort as code, not an image. And a better/complete example of your code to see where it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxSpeed = {
    car: 300, 
    bike: 60, 
    motorbike: 200, 
    airplane: 1000,
    helicopter: 400, 
    rocket: 8 * 60 * 60
};

var sortable= [];

for (var vehicle in maxSpeed) {
    sortable.push([vehicle, maxSpeed[vehicle]]);
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/408487)